# AssertJ comparing double values

Tags: compare, double, offset, assertj

I would like to compare double values with AssertJ. I dont catch why my test is failing.

```
@Test
public void testInterestToQuote() {
    double result = BasicCalculator.accumulationFactorByYearsAndInterest(years, interest)
    Assertions.assertThat(result).isCloseTo(expected, Assertions.offset(0.1d))
}
```

Exception is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
   <7.256571590148141E-5>
to be close to:
   <7.25>
by less than <0.1> but difference was <7.249927434284099>.
(a difference of exactly <0.1> being considered valid)
```

Why does Assertion fail?

Answer (score 2):

It was late yesterday, but 7.256571590148141E-5 is not as I thought, 7.25.., because E-5 moves the point 5 to the left, so it is 0.0000725...

Comment: In case somebody else is looking for assertj decimal point comparison with a certain precision degree and ends up here. The correct way to do that would be something like:

`assertThat(result).isEqualTo(expected, withPrecision(2d))`

Comment: The above comment is surely the real answer ?

Answer (score 1):

ad **assertj decimal point comparison with Double/Float**:

In my case I was comparing Double to Float

`assertThat(resultDouble).isEqualTo(expectedFloat);`

-> `assertThat(resultDouble).isEqualTo(expectedDouble);`